# How to verify the generated OTP using TOTP algorithm

Tags: c#, security, two-factor-authentication, one-time-password

We have generated the OTP using Totp algorithm and it would be live for short time. Can you please tell me how to verify generated OTP with user entered otp. Is there any method for compare those or need to store the password somewhere and validate with the entered otp.

Please suggest me which way is best for verifying the OTP that generated using Totp algorithm.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

To verify the token you need to generate the OTP yourself on the server side and do a constant time string equality comparison between it and the user provided OTP.

You may need to generate some older tokens to check too, in case the user entered a token but the time period passed before you could check. You should probably limit how old a token can be, but it's up to you to decide how old you deem a token to still be valid.

Answer (score 0):

The technique is to use the same seed data and encoding method that the app/hardware token used to generate the OTP code, then compare this against the supplied code.  It is then up to you if you check either side of the current time window to allow for a degree time drift between the server and the users app/device.